# Can I use anything other than Photoshop for my needs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

I have been using Photoshop (I believe 7) for what seems like forever on Windows 7 and my Photoshop was a pirated copy.

However my computer crashed and I have acquired a new one with Windows 10. Now I am not sure wether or not to splurge on Photoshop or if something free will serve me just fine.

What I use in Photoshop are the following:

- Layers.
- Magic Wand Tool (with different tolerance).
- Selection tools (the lasso).
- Dodge, Burn.
- Brushes (mainly pixel soft and hard, in different sizes).
- Zoom in to pixels.
- Colour correction (saturation especially).
- Cut and Paste.
- Resizing selected areas and pasted pieces.
- Text tool (sometimes with layer effect, but this is not a need).
- Rotate items, and mirror items.
- Directly scan my hand drawn artwork and whiten the background, correct colours etc.
- Make images ready for printing at high resolution (300ppi or higher. My scanner actually does 1200ppi).
- I save work in PSD when I work on them due to layers etc.
- Save finished work as JPG.

Will anything other than Photoshop do for me? I cant really afford that software now.

I do not use it for photo editing, it's more for "scrap booking" really. Cut and paste from images onto blank canvas (usually international A4 or A5), as well as editing hand drawn images.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) would have everything you need.

Comment: Ive read that the swich is hard when your used to PS.... but seems like I must give it a try :D